# Error when doing code-first Entity Framework while having SQL Server installed on my computer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hey guys you have been so helpful in the past so I was hoping you could give me some insight into my latest issue.

So I've recently begun delving into Entity Framework. I've been doing mostly SQL only work for a while, but my boss wants me to begin learning MVC and Entity Framework.

Well to begin this I got onto Microsoft Virtual Academy and started the integrating Entity Framework into MVC. I do have SQL Server on my machine. So first I created my MVC application and in models added my class (`Album` for this exercise and `MusicContext` as the context class) using the code they provided.

Then using the add item with scaffolding option I added the controller. Please note that for this point I did not use the plus sign when selecting my context class, so no extra connection string was created. So in `web.config` I have this connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
             AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20150722102254.mdf;
             Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20150722102254;
             Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now when they run the program and add `/albums` to the url they get a page that allows them to edit this new database that has been created for the project. On mine however I am getting an error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

So it looks as though it is having trouble accessing my localdb. I have no passwords or authentication set up for this localdb and am an administrator on this computer. I apologize for this wall of text and will try to keep a close eye on this question so if there is any additional information you would need to answer this question please let me know and I will try to answer promptly.

Thank you for your help

Edit 1:

Hey so I found the database my program is trying to create and it is a security issue. I realized my normal localdb that I use is apparently more a network thing and so I actually connected to (Localdb)\v11.0. There I found what was happening. Apparently there is some permissions problem in there. The only account with sysadmin rights is the sa user. I attempted to give my windows account rights and I was able to under the logins folder in that server, but when trying to give myself rights under the database properties it didn't work. I noticed that when adding a scaffolded item to my program where it generates my controller and connection string there is an option when picking a context class that adds a second connections string. It keeps the first connection string I have listed above, but then adds this string right below it:

```
 <add name="WebApplication2Context" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=WebApplication2Context-20150722110908; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|WebApplication2Context-20150722110908.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried this on my home pc and was able to get my program to work with the default string and did not have to add the secondary connection string. Can anyone shed some light onto what is going on here? If I have to keep using the second connection string while at work that is fine, I would just like to know why it is happening and what to do about it in the future. Also if someone could explain a little more about what exactly the button that creates the second connection string is doing that would also be great.

Thanks again!

Edit 2:
Not sure if anyone is even still looking at this question but if so I believe I have cracked a little of the code. When I made my Context class (MusicContext) it had no constructor and as such did not call to the base(Connection name). So before My context class looked like this.

```
 public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

Now it looks like this

```
  public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        public MusicContext()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

So now my remaining question is this. Why does the previous context class work on my home computer that only has visual studio, but does not work on my work computer? If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it greatly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go into the SQL Server Object Explorer panel in VS and try to create the database manually. Expand the "SQL Server" tree and then "(localdb)", right click "Databases" and choose "Add New Database". You'll probably want to give it a more descriptive name than the `aspnet-WebApplication1-2050722102243` garbage, so just edit your Web.config afterward to set the new name.

Comment: Well the only reason I am not doing that is I am actually trying to figure out why on my computer this error is occurring, but on the instructor computer it all works out just fine. This is just a throwaway project, but I'd like to know for future reference what the big difference is that's causing this error. Thank you for the quick reply though!

Comment: Ideally, Entity Framework *should* generate this MDF file for you, but in my personal experience, I've found it's pretty hit or miss. I'm not sure why it often fails, but the only sure fire way to handle it is to just always create the database yourself. Then, you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Alright so new development. I actually connected to the database listed as the data source in that connection string, (LocalDb)\v11.0. When i looked I realized I do not have rights to write to or change that database. So I'm assuming that because I did not personally install SQL Server on my computer this is what is causing the issue with the permissions. I tried to change some settings of that server when I connected and it said access denied.    Edit: Just saw the permissions. There is an sa account that has all the permissions. I believe I'm figuring it out

Comment: I added some more information under Edit 1 in my post. This might give some more explanation as to my problem and if you happen to know the answer I would love to hear back from you.